# Quebrar resultado de query em 2 linhas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Boa tarde! Estou com a seguinte duvida

A minha query esta retornando uma unica linha, mas necessitaria que ela retornasse duas linhas, onde a primeira linha seria o retorno de “B” e a outra o retorno de “C”

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

```
select b.*,c.* from portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
inner join portal_sega_user b  -- secretaria secundaria
on b.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIAPRINCIPAL 
inner join portal_sega_user c -- secretaria secundaria
on c.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIASECUNDARIA
where a.USUARIO = 'Willian'
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641423/how-to-return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-in-t-sql-using-group-by ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divida a query em duas consultas e junte com UNION

```
select b.* from portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
inner join portal_sega_user b  -- secretaria secundaria
on b.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIAPRINCIPAL 
where a.USUARIO = 'Willian'

UNION 

select c.* from portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
inner join portal_sega_user c -- secretaria secundaria
on c.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIASECUNDARIA
where a.USUARIO = 'Willian'
```

Obs: O número, nome e tipo das colunas deve ser o mesmo nos dois resultados do select, se necessário adicione alias nos selects com nome de colunas.

Comment: Opa! Obrigado, Era exatamente isso que estava tentando fazer, mas me fugiu utilizar o union. 
grato!

Answer (score 2):

Faça um `UNION ALL` com duas consultas:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
 INNER JOIN portal_sega_user b -- secretaria secundaria
    ON b.usuario = a.secretariaprincipal
 INNER JOIN portal_sega_user c -- secretaria secundaria
    ON c.usuario = a.secretariasecundaria
 WHERE a.usuario = 'Willian'
UNION ALL 
SELECT c.*
  FROM portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
 INNER JOIN portal_sega_user b -- secretaria secundaria
    ON b.usuario = a.secretariaprincipal
 INNER JOIN portal_sega_user c -- secretaria secundaria
    ON c.usuario = a.secretariasecundaria
 WHERE a.usuario = 'Willian'
```

Um detalhe, o uso do `UNION` não garante que sua consulta retorne duas linhas, o `UNION ALL` sim.

Answer (score 1):

Separe suas junções e faça uma união de dois SELECTs:

```
select b.* from portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
inner join portal_sega_user b  -- secretaria secundaria
on b.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIAPRINCIPAL 
where a.USUARIO = 'Willian'
UNION
select c.* from portal_sega_user a -- perfil 
inner join portal_sega_user c -- secretaria secundaria
on c.USUARIO = a.SECRETARIASECUNDARIA
where a.USUARIO = 'Willian'
```